# gnuplot+latex+postscript eps enhanced terminal: key text misaligned

Tags: latex, gnuplot, eps

i am compiling some eps graphs with gnuplot using the following terminal line:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced eps color dashed rounded dl 4 "Times-Roman" 24
```

An example:

```
p 'file1' u 5:6 w p t 't=0.5 ms',\
  'file2' u 5:6 w p t '    1 ms',\
  'file3' u 5:6 w p t '    2 ms'
```

I added extra spaces in the key to have a nice alignment for the labels in the key. This alignment works fine if i open the resulting eps with ghostviewer, but if i compile it within a latex file

```
$ latex
 ... pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) ...
```

then the text in the key is misaligned. It happens especially if i am using special typesetting like subscripts or superscripts:

```
p 'file1' u 5:6 w p t 't_{something}=0.5 ms'
```

then the text will be totally jeopardized, like overlapping text or weird alignments, but only after compiling within latex.

Have you ever seen this before?

Many thanks

edit: add a minimal example

gnuplot script:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced eps color dashed rounded dl 4 "Times-Roman" 24
set key spacing 1.1 samplen 1.2 top left
set output 'out.eps'
p 3*x w p lc 1 t 't=0.5 ms',\
  2*x w p lc 2 t '    1 ms'
```

everything fine if I run:

```
$gv out.eps
```

i compile the following latex file:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,onecolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\journal{Combustion and Flame}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{out}
 \caption{caption.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

using the following script ($name=latex file name):

```
latex $name.tex
latex $name.tex
dvips $name.dvi
ps2pdf $name.ps
```

using acroread, evince or xpdf, the 't=0.5 ms' label overlaps the corresponding key symbol, while visualizing out.eps on gv shows everything fine, with key text aligned to the right.

FURTHER EDIT:

replacing elsarticle with book solves the problem!

LAST EDIT:

compiling with pdflatex instead of latex solves the problem

Comment: Please show a full but minimal example of *all* steps: A minimal gnuplot script (with e.g. `plot x`), a minimal LaTeX document, the compilation steps, and which viewer you use to view which file (dvi, ps or pdf).

Comment: Thank you @Christoph, added a minimal example

Comment: ok @Christoph, actually the problem disappeared compiling with pdflatex. Thank you anyway

Comment: That's the benefit of a minimal example :)